# Find a string when it occurs after another string, and before the next occurrence of a third string

Tags: regex

I am trying to use RegEx to find a string, but only when it occurs after another string and before the next occurrence of a third string.

Using this text:

```
one (random text) abc (random text) end two (random text) abc (random text) end three (random text) abc (random text) end
```

I want to find "abc", only if it comes after "two" and before the next "end".  If there is and "end" after the "two", with no "abc" in between, return no match at all.

The following expression will match from "two", to the next "end", but I don't know where to put the "abc":

```
(?s)(?i)two(.*?)end
```

The following expression does not work because it finds an "abc" between "two", and the "end" that comes after "three":

```
(?s)(?i)two(.*?)abc(.*?)end
```

I am using this within a program that uses RegEx to decide whether a file meets a condition, so I am not sure what language it is using.  The program just needs to know whether the condition is present, so what the expression would actually return for a result is unimportant - only whether there is a match or not.

Any help would be appreciated!

Edited to clarify that there is other random text throughout and to clarify the requested behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try the following pattern:

```
two(?:(?!(?:two|abc|end)).)*abc(?:(?!(?:two|abc|end)).)*end
```

Here is an explanation of the pattern:

```
two                         - match 'two'
(?:(?!(?:two|abc|end)).)*   - match anything other than 'two', 'abc', or 'end'
abc                         - match 'abc'
(?:(?!(?:two|abc|end)).)*   - match anything other than 'two', 'abc', or 'end'
end                         - match 'end'
```

### Demo

The basic idea is to use negative lookaheads to cautiously progress with the rules of your pattern.

Comment: Hi @Tim Biegeleisen, thanks for the response.  I'm very sorry, I forgot to clarify that there as random additional text in before and after the "abc", so I can't search for the entire "two abc end" string as I don't know what else it might contain.  (I will edit my question to clarify this).  So what I need is a way to look for "two", followed by "abc", followed by "end", where "end" and "abc" may occur multiple times throught the rest of the text, and to stop looking with no match returned if "end" is found after "two" before "abc" has been found.

Comment: @Rob I updated my answer with a new pattern.  Much uglier than before, but I believe it fits your requirements.